# Identify old boardgame

Tags: identify-this-game, board-game-adaptations

I found this game at my friend's parents. They said they custom made this from an old PC game (90's). But they forgot the name. Here is a picture of it. [image: https://imgur.com/a/Cw40YXL] The goal is to get your pieces across the board.

Its name has been lost for more than 2 decades. Thank you.

Comment: Now you have the name, I suggest neatly engraving or wood-pokering (?) that name onto the side or endpieces.  So in another 20 years the next generation can find it.  And the name/date of the maker too,

Comment: It looks great! Now I really want to try it.

Comment: It reminds me of Quoridor, from 1997, but as already stated by others, Shuttles includes sliding rows, while the Quoridor board is static.

Comment: @DavidS. Quoridor substituted movable walls for the shuttles, so I wouldn't say it's static.

Comment: @Scott: Right. It's not true that the entire game is static, just the board. The game as a whole is still modular thanks to the aforementioned placeable walls.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a wooden version of [Shuttles](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1916/shuttles) (named for the rows that can be moved sideways) aka Impasse, Labymaster, Labyrinth, or Traject. The PC game was an implementation of this older board game from 1973.

[image]

The PC game was also called [Shuttles](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/shuttles/9wzdncrdcr7b).

[image]

Comment: Did you purposefully choose the image from the PC game meant to give me nightmares, or is that just happenstance?